# Prevent multiple threads writing the same file

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file-io, mutex

i am designing and developing an api where multiple threads are downloading files from the net and then write it to disk.

if it is used incorrectly it could happen that the same file is downloaded and written by more than one threads, which will lead to an exception at the moment of writing to disk.

i would like to avoid this problem with a `lock() { ... }` around the part that writes the file, but obviously i dont want to lock with a global object, just something that is related to that specific file so that not all threads are locked when a file is written.

i hope this question is understandable.

Comment: Use [memory-mapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) file?

Comment: @Sinatr: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Using exceptions to handle this type of race condition seems appropriate. What is the problem? I don't see the need for a lock.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18932851/62640

Comment: @Bananamansam such a global lock is exactly what i want to avoid.

Comment: @user2684301: A thread collision may not result in an exception, but could instead involve content being interleaved inappropriately, depending on exactly how the writing is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using ReaderWriterLockSlim

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim fileLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();


fileLock.EnterWriteLock();
try
{
   //write your file here
}
finally
{
    fileLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

Comment: sounds interesting: so will the second thread wait automatically until the first is finished?

Comment: Yep. And if you open the link, first line says `Represents a lock that is used to manage access to a resource, allowing multiple threads for reading or exclusive access for writing.`

Comment: This looks like a great solution if there's interest in reading from the threads, in addition to writing.  I can see a spiffy thread-safe file wrapper class which uses class and some stream objects to fully abstract safe reading and writing.

Comment: yes, `fileLock.EnterWriteLock()` won't allow other threads in. you can create an object to work with files and utilize `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to secure writing.

Comment: i gave it a quick try in my code, but it didnt work, so probably i am missing something. do i have to use the same instance of ReaderWriterLockSLim on all threads? do i also have to wrap all read accesses with such a lock?

Comment: He's only writing, not reading, so this isn't really any different than a global exclusive lock; he wants to be ensuring that threads are only waiting on other writes *to the same file*.

Comment: there should be a dictionary of files currently processed. where key is the file name and the value - custom class(say `FileSync`) with the implementation based on `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Comment: if i have to keep a global set of processed files, i just can handle the locking myself without that ReaderWriterLockSlim , right?

Comment: I'm not aware of your design, collection of items being currently processed seems logical to me....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx `TextWriter.Synchronized`?

Answer (score 3):

So what you want to be able to do is synchronize a bunch of actions based no a given key.  In this case, that key can be an absolute file name.  We can implement this as a dictionary that maps a key to some synchronization object.  This could be either an object to lock on, if we want to implement a blocking synchronization mechanism, or a `Task` if we want to represent an asynchronous method of running the code when appropriate; I went with the later.  I also went with a `ConcurrentDictionary` to let it handle the synchronization, rather than handling it manually, and used `Lazy` to ensure that each task was created exactly once:

```
public class KeyedSynchronizer<TKey>
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<Task>> dictionary;
    public KeyedSynchronizer(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<Task>>(
            comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public Task ActOnKey(TKey key, Action action)
    {
        var dictionaryValue = dictionary.AddOrUpdate(key,
            new Lazy<Task>(() => Task.Run(action)),
                (_, task) => new Lazy<Task>(() =>
                    task.Value.ContinueWith(t => action())));
        return dictionaryValue.Value;
    }

    public static readonly KeyedSynchronizer<TKey> Default =
        new KeyedSynchronizer<TKey>();
}
```

You can now create an instance of this synchronizer, and then specify actions along with the keys (files) that they correspond to.  You can be confident that the actions won't be executed until any previous actions on that file have completed.  If you want to wait until that action completes, then you can `Wait` on the task, if you don't have any need to wait, then you can just not.  This also allows you to do your processing asynchronously by awaiting the task.

Comment: [The documentation on ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_AddOrUpdate__0_System_Func__0__1__System_Func__0__1__1__) says: "If you call `AddOrUpdate` simultaneously on different threads, `addValueFactory` may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call". This implies that there are edge cases where two tasks might be run at the same time for a single key.

Comment: @vivicat Correct.  That's why the lazy is there to ensure it only runs once.

Comment: But you're creating the lazy inside `addValueFactory`. So this would just produce two separate lazy objects that execute simultaneously.

Comment: @vivicat You're creating two lazy objects, yes.  But only one of them is ever actually returned by the dictionary, because of the concurrentdictionary guarentee, so only one of them ever has it's value materialized.  The other is a lazy that's created and never has its value function run.

Comment: Ah so in this situation the extra call to `addValueFactory` creates a stray lazy item, but the item returned by AddOrUpdate is always the item created by the *other* call and present in the dictionary? That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, and resolved it by `lock()`ing on the `StreamWriter` object in question:

```
private Dictionary<string, StreamWriter>  _writers;  // Consider using a thread-safe dictionary

void  WriteContent(string file, string content)
    {
    StreamWriter  writer;
    if (_writers.TryGetValue(file, out writer))
        lock (writer)
            writer.Write(content);
    // Else handle missing writer
    }
```

That's from memory, it may not compile.  I'd read up on Andrew's solution (I will be), as it may be more exactly what you need... but this is super-simple, if you just want a quick-and-dirty.

Comment: This assumes that the list of writers is constant throughout the whole process.  If it's not, this won't work, as you'd need to be adding items to the dictionary from multiple threads, and it's not designed to support that.

Comment: Yep.  My assumption is that the OP is creating a writer either when a user initiates downloading a file, or on the first write operation.  If the design calls for discarding and re-creating writers occasionally, it would be necessary to lock on some more persistent object.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make it an answer with some explanation.

Windows already have *something* like you want, idea behind is simple: to allow multiple processes access same file and to carry on all writing/reading operations, so that: 1) all processes operates with the most recent data of that file 2) multiple writing or reading occurs without waiting (if possible).

It's called [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx). I was using it for IPC mostly (without file), so can't provide an example, but there should be [some](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx).

You could mimic MMF behavior by using some buffer and sort of layer on top of it, which will redirect all reading/writing operations to that buffer and periodically flush updated content into physical file.

P.S: try to look also for file-sharing (open file for shared reading/writing).